# Kendo multiselect filtering after setting value

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, multi-select, kendo-multiselect

I have a fairly complicated situation, in which I have a kendo grid that has some details for each record. Inside those details, there is a kendo multiselect that offers server side filtering capabilities. 
I want to be able to "edit" the details of each record and change the value of the multiselect. In the case that the user decides to cancel the modification, I want to be able to revert back to the old values for the input.

The code i am using for this is the following:

```
function onEditCancel(e) {
    revertMultiSelect(e.model.uid); 
    //using the uid will help us to only revert the desired multiselect 
}

function revertMultiSelect(uid)
{
    var originalState = originalStateDictionary[uid]; 
    //this dictionary has the desired initial state
    if (originalState != null) {
        var multiSelect = $("#my_multiselect" + uid).data("kendoMultiSelect");                    
        multiSelect.dataSource.data(originalState.InitialDataSource);                    
        multiSelect.value(originalState.InitialSelectedIds);
    }
}
```

The process is working completely fine when the only single modification to the multiselect value involves deleting, after clicking cancel on the row, the state of the multiselect is reverted succesfully (old values are prepopulated).

HOWEVER, once I decide to add a new value (after a server side filtering operation has been completed) and I decide to cancel the operation, this stops the revertMultiSelect function stops working as expected.

To be more specific, once the code reaches the line `multiSelect.value(originalState.InitialSelectedIds);` filtering is triggered once more with an emtpy value (I can intercept the filtering request on my server side). This is not being triggered when my only operation was to delete a value, and causes the multi select to lose ALL selected values and appear empty.

I get the sense that if I can somehow prevent the filtering to occur on the cancel action, I could stop the multiselect from erasing itself.I have tried resetting the filter as indicated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22010796/kendo-multiselect-value-setting-bug)  but had no success.

Is there something I am missing?
Greetings
Luis.

**UPDATE** I added the following JSFiddle
[http://jsfiddle.net/8us1fvy1/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/8us1fvy1/2)

*Workflow 1:*

1. Delete an Item
2. Click on cancel button
3. No indicator changes

*Workflow 2:*

1. Add an element (i.e. type 'Chef')
2. See how the filter event is fired once
3. Click on cancel button
4. See how the filter event is fired once more (I dont know why in this case the values dont get deleted, in my scenario they do. The important piece is, however, that filter is fired once more)

Comment: I opened a ticket with my company's subscription for the same issue almost a month ago. It's a bug. You need to clear all datasource request filters server side while you catch a bogus request.

Comment: Did you open this issue on the kendo forum? Would you be so kind to tell me where can I find this ticket?

Comment: It was private ticket. However the point was that the datasource of my widget  (Dropdown in my case) was triggering the filter event with contains:'' after some client operation over the widget . I solved by clearing the filter server side. Hope this will help you as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea if Kendo team is planning to change this behavior so if you can't change on server side code you can add this function to your multiselect dataSource as workaround:

```
requestStart: function(e){
    if(e.sender.filter().filters.length === 0){
        // cancel event to prevent sending request to server
        e.preventDefault();

        // trigger revert function again to set original state data
        revertMultiSelect();
    }
}
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8us1fvy1/2/

Comment: Thanks! This works for me, however i removed the secondary call to reverMultiSelect() as this would create an infinite loop (setting the value in the multiselect triggers a requeststart and so on)